# Using Powershell to sort through text file and combine like terms?

Tags: sorting, powershell

In this hypothetical world, let's say that there is a school that offers classes A through Z. In order to graduate, you merely have to get so many hours in so many certain courses. This is recorded in this way (number = hours, letter = class):

```
Sunday 01/10/15 - 2A, 5H, 3Z 
Monday 01/11/15 - 2A, 5Z, 5B
Wednesday 01/15/15 - 2A, 4Y, 6R
```

At the end of the individual record for the student, it would combine all numbers that had a matching letter, therefor showing the hour total in each class.

```
Sunday 01/15 - 2A, 5H, 3Z 
Monday 02/15 - 2A, 5Z, 5B
Wednesday 01/15/15 - 2A, 4Y, 6R

6A, 5B, 5H, 6R, 4Y, 8Z.
```

While I am comfortable importing data and sorting data, I am having a hard time figuring out how to script it to add up all the numbers that share the same letter. If this data was hundreds of lines long and there was three instances of 2B in those lines, I would like it to be able to pick those out and show me 6B. What am I missing? Am I using the wrong tool for the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a dictionary of sums. In Powershell that would be a hash table of sums. Everytime you see a letter, look it up in your top level hash table and see if it is there. If not create a sum for that letter and add it to the hash table.

When you are done you can take the keys to the hash table and sort them, and then print out all the letter, sum pairs as key-value pairs.

I will write some code for that, but I need to have a coffee first :).

And here it is...

```
$slst = ("2A","5H","3Z","2A","5Z","5B","2A","4Y","6R")

$sums = @{}

foreach($s in $slst)
{
  $skey = $s[1]
  $sval = $s[0] - 48
  $sums[$skey] += $sval
}

$sums.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name
```

Note there was a longer version here before, but someone pointed out that you don't need to initialize dictionaries explicity in powershell.

Comment: Might want to check that operator ;).  Using = will replace, += will accumulate.

Comment: Perfect. This gives me something fun to study. I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad you appreciated it. I learned something too as it so happens :)